# How do you use boxed closures in FnMut contexts?

Tags: closures, rust

How can you use a boxed closure in a context that requires a `FnMut` type, e.g.

```
pub fn main() {
  for n in (0..10).map(Box::new(|i| i * 2)) {
    println!("{}", n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `Box<FnMut(...)>` does not impl the `FnMut` trait, but this is something that could potentially be improved in the future.

Comment: I have the feeling you're asking the wrong question. What problem do you really want to solve?

Comment: I want to store a `Map` or `FlatMap` iterator in a struct, with a closure as a parameter. Thanks to reddit, I've now just manually created a struct that implements `FnMut`, and used that as the parameter to `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Box` implements the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait, you can simply derefence your `box`ed function:

```
fn main() {
    let boxed_fn = Box::new(|i| i * 2);
    for n in (0..10).map(*boxed_fn) {
        println!("{}", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that the type of the `map` expression is now difficult to express?

Comment: What do you mean by "difficult to express"?

Comment: I think the type can't be written in a "closed form", without extra generic parameters, e.g. http://is.gd/pttpBX. This is problematic when trying to store iterators. Usually my solution for this is to box the closure!

Comment: Dereferencing the box in this cotext will consume it and move the boxed function out of the box into the iterator because `map` takes its argument by value.

Comment: So if I want to describe the type of the resulting value (e.g. to store it in a struct), I can't, because the type of the closure parameter is no longer `Box<FnMut ...>`, it's `UnnameableType`.